# Accepting and char in url param

Tags: django

How can I accept any char in url param?

```
(?P<slug>[-\w]+)
```

The above is only accepting dashes and alphanum chars.

Comment: Not sure if you were just using that as an example, but [slugs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/glossary/#term-slug) can only contain letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot matches any character:

```
(?P<slug>.+)
```